# How to call the web service simultaneously without waiting for a response swift ios?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, dispatch-queue

We have to send the captured image simultaneously in a background thread. we have used this DispatchQueue to call below API.

```
@IBAction func gallery(_ sender: Any) {
       func upload(imageData: Data,fileName: String,completion:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ error:String) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
    //code
    })}
}
@IBAction func camera(_ sender: Any) {
       func upload(imageData: Data,fileName: String,completion:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ error:String) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
    //code
    })}
}
@IBAction func contine(_ sender: Any) {
       func session(session: String,completion:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ error:String) -> Void) {
  )}
}
```

The problem is I have another service "session" web service to call after captured the documents. No need to wait for a response. But I can't get value for this "session" web service. How to call the service simultaneously without waiting for a response.

Comment: You can add multiple completion handlers, like the one you already have, to represents actions that should be handled after other steps. For example, you can add another callback called `encodingCompleted` or `diskWriteCompleted` and use them as appropriate.

Comment: second response not depends on first response.

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you, I'm not fully understanding your use case. Could you share the code where you call the `upload` function?

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: Try to create your own *concurrent* queue or mark queues with different `qos`